# Creating Multiple Users

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have made a sales management website in aps.net .It works perfectly fine for one person who logs in and uses the site.

How can I open multiple google chrome tabs for my asp.net web site and different user's can use the site at the same time or in other words. Multiple staff can be created that later on login and participate in sale who are probably at different counters.

Comment: You can't login with different users by just opening new tabs. The user is normally stored per browser. You would have to open another browser (for example IE and Firefox) and there you can login with another user

Comment: How google works. You can use different users in different tabs. Perhaps the different cookie name for different users.

Comment: What is your question here? How you can allow different users to be logged on at the same time, on the same computer, in the same browser - but different tabs? Or how you can add user accounts to the application? Is it a ASP.NET MVC or web forms application and which version are you using? As it stands this question is impossible to answer as it isn't clear what you are asking and vital detail is missing.

Comment: I actually wanted to authenticate every user @dav_i solved the problem thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually asked a very similar question on C# chat a while back. [Travis J suggested something similar to the following](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/13326235#13326235):

```
var authStore = new AuthenticationStore();

foreach(var user in users)
{
    if(UserAuthentication.Verify(user))
    {
        authStore.Add(user);
        // store auth token in session or similar
    }
}
```